# how to use "not only, but also"

Tags: word-usage, idioms, auxiliary-verbs

Tom plays the guitar very well.  He is good at singing, too.  In this case, which of the following would be correct?

1. Tom not only plays the guitar very well but also sings very well.
2. Tom doesn't only play the guitar very well but also sing very well.

I want to know if you need "do/does" before not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It would be

> Tom doesn't only play the guitar very well but also sing**s** very well.

*Sings* is parallel to the whole of *doesn't play*, so needs the final -s.

*But also does sing very well* is grammatical, but would only be used if there had been a suggestion that he didn't sing well.

Comment: Note that (1) is idiomatic too.

Comment: Are both 1 and 2 acceptable?

Comment: Yes, they both are.